# Wordpress - function for a specific query

Tags: php, wordpress

Is there a way to do an 'if' statement that is true for a specific query, that I named somehow? I want to do it in a function in the function.php, as I can do it like

```
if ( $query->is_main_query() ){}
```

but it is for the main query, and the query that I want to use as the condition isn't the main query this time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can always do the logic inside the pre_get_posts filter and apply if conditions over there. For ex.

```
add_filter('pre_get_posts', 'limit_archive_posts' ,5);
function limit_archive_posts($query){
    if ($query->is_category) {
        $query->set('posts_per_page', 3);
    }
    if($query->is_single == 1){
        $query->set('posts_per_page', 1);
    }
    return $query;
}
```

Comment: So I can only target a specific query with its arguments?

Comment: Yes, You also can use the following conditions for category check given here : if ('magazine' == $query->query_vars['category_name'])

Comment: Thanks, this condition scheme helped me!

Answer (score 0):

you can create function like this:

```
   public function new_venue()
  {          
    $new_boolean = false;
   if ( $query->is_main_query() ){
      $new_boolean = true;
    }
      return 
  }
```

Comment: But what if the query isn't the main query?

Comment: what you try to say?

Comment: If there is a random query somewhere on a subpage, which isn't the main query, can I target it in the function?

Comment: yes you can. you have to call that function acquired file in required file